# How to choose a time/date and put it into a timer-task?

Tags: java, date, timer

As I corrected my use of some features instead of others, I post this. I try to use JSpinner to choose a Date and Time and put it then into a timer and the trigger must be the Date and Time I choosed.

How could I use it to change the time too by moving the arrows and to put the date and time in the timer ?

```
    import java.awt.BorderLayout;
    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.JLabel;
    import javax.swing.JPanel;
    import javax.swing.JSpinner;
    import javax.swing.SpinnerDateModel;
    import javax.swing.SpinnerModel;
    import java.util.Calendar;
    import java.util.Date;
    import javax.swing.Timer;

    public class SpinnerDateSample {
     public static void main(String args[]) {
     JFrame frame = new JFrame("JSpinner Sample");
     frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


     SpinnerModel model1 = new SpinnerDateModel();
     JSpinner spinner1 = new JSpinner(model1);
     spinner1.addChangeListener(new CalendarListener());

     JLabel label1 = new JLabel("Dates/Date");
     JPanel panel1 = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
     panel1.add(label1, BorderLayout.WEST);
     panel1.add(spinner1, BorderLayout.CENTER);
     frame.add(panel1, BorderLayout.CENTER);

     frame.setSize(200, 90);
     frame.setVisible(true);
    }
   }

   private class CalendarListener implements ChangeListener {
    public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e)  {
     JSpinner jSpinner = (JSpinner) e.getSource();
     Date date = (Date) jSpinner.getValue();
     long delay = date.getTime() - System.currentTimeMillis();
      timerStart();
      if (delay > 0) {
      timer.setInitialDelay((int) delay);
      timer.restart();
     }
    }   
   }

   TimerStart() {
    this.timer = new Timer(Integer.MAX_VALUE, (ActionEvent evt) -> {
     System.out.println("okey");
   });}
```

Comment: I'm not clear on what your actual question is, but I see that you have Swing code and are using a java.util.Timer as well as a TimerTask, and this worries me. Swing applications don't work well with this type of Timer as this can cause hard to debug intermittent threading errors. Usually you're much better off using Swing Timers (javax.swing.Timer) with Swing applications.

Comment: Thanks, I will change it to swing. I try to launch a task from a timer, on a given time and date, which I could choose from a list or something.

Comment: *I don't know well how to choose a time...*  Usually with [JSpinners](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/spinner.html).  One for the hour, one for the minute, and one for AM / PM.  The minute spinner can be in 5 or 15 minute intervals.

Comment: Good, I will try to set something with JSpinner.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Why not make an Answer of your comments so this Question can be closed?

Comment: I edited my Question, I was trying to use JSpinner and Swing Timer, just with some implementation problems. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`TimerTask`  is a legacy class, rather you can use `ScheduledExecutorService` for executing a task at scheduled intervals, which is a best practice as shown below:

**Selection6Runable class:**

```
public class Selection6Runable implements Runnable {
         public void run() {
              //Add code for Selection6 Logic, 
             // this code will be run everytime when the scheduler runs
          }
     }
```

**Using the above code:**

```
ScheduledExecutorService scheduledService= Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
//Change the below time interval according 
//to the data received i.e., CalDcB.getSelectedItem()
scheduledService.scheduleAtFixedRate(()-> new Selection6Runable(), 
                        0, 1000L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

You can look [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) for more details

Comment: @GiaRui: no, this will cause the exact same threading issues that I mentioned before in my comment to your original question. If your repeating code makes Swing calls, you're **far** better off not using this but rather using a Swing Timer.